# understanding Do Carmo's Differential form

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms

From Do Carmo’s Differential form and its application

To each tangent space $\mathbb R^3_p$ we can associate its dual space $(\mathbb R^3_p)^*$ which is the set of linear maps $\phi: \mathbb R^3_p \to \mathbb R$. A basis for $(\mathbb R^3_p)^*$ is obtained by taking $(dx_i)_p$ i=1,2,3 where $x_i:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$ is the map which assigns to each point its $ i^{th}$ coordinate.
The set
{$(dx_i)_p$:$i=1,2,3$}
is in fact the dual basis of {$(e_i)_p$} since

$(dx_i)_p(e_j)=\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}=0$ if $i=j$ and $ 1$ if  $i\neq j$.

First thing I want to know what is this $(dx_i)_p$?

And Second how we got $(dx_i)_p(e_j)=\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(dx_i)_p$ is the Jacobian of the map $x_i$ at the point $p$. To see how to compute this, consider the map 
$$x_1 : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$(x,y,z) \mapsto x.$$
Then we have
$$
(dx_1)_p = \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x)|_p & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x)|_p & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(x)|_p
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Similarly,
$$(dx_2)_p = \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$(dx_3)_p = \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now, the maps $(dx_i)_p$ clearly define a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$ given by left multiplying any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by the matrices above. These give a basis for the dual space $(\mathbb{R}^3_p)^*$ since any linear map $\phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ takes the form
$$\phi(x,y,z) = \alpha x + \beta y + \gamma z$$
for some $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, we can write
$$\phi = \alpha (dx_1)_p + \beta (dx_2)_p + \gamma (dx_3)_p.$$

The equation $(dx_i)_p(e_j) = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}$ follows directly from our expressions for $(dx_i)_p$ above.